# Is it OK to have huge object library for using with BlendDataLibraries?

Tags: blend-files

I'm developing command-line scripts that would need to get and append some objects from library, and the library is going to have over 9000 objects.
Will it overwhelm blender to have such huge library?

Question is whether blender loads and parses whole library file when it's opened, or it only parses it on demand when a particular object requested.

Comment: You might want to add a little more information here. Things like how big in terms of vertex count, materials etc. are your objects, what hardware are you using...

Comment: Does behaviour of blender depends on such parameters?

Comment: why yes, of course it does. More vertices means more calculations which obviously require more computing power.

Comment: so, you don't know if it loads all objects in file or only those that requested?

Comment: All I know is that the appending Blender instance doesn't work like a database engine and it doesn't "stream" the .blend file. There is also no separate "search index" to speed up the process, so I guess it loads all the objects.